# Why does everyauth crash with 'undefined is not a function'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, everyauth

My code is as follows

```
var express = require('express'),
    everyauth = require('everyauth'),
  util = require('util'),
  Promise = everyauth.Promise,
  users = require('./users');

everyauth.twitter
  .consumerKey('')
  .consumerSecret('')
  .findOrCreateUser(function(session, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, twitterUserData) {
    console.log('pre promise');
    var promise = new Promise();
   users.findOrCreateByTwitterData(twitterUserData, promise);
    return promise;
  })
  .redirectPath('/');
```

It prints 'pre promise'and then crash is as follows

```
pre promise

/.../node_modules/everyauth/lib/modules/everymodule.js:348
  throw err;
        ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object._findOrCreateUser ( .../test.js:12:19)
    at Object.exec ( .../node_modules/everyauth/lib/step.js:47:21)
    at  .../node_modules/everyauth/lib/stepSequence.js:26:38
    at [object Object].fulfill ( .../node_modules/everyauth/lib/promise.js:42:25)
    at  .../node_modules/everyauth/lib/stepSequence.js:29:23
    at [object Object].fulfill ( .../node_modules/everyauth/lib/promise.js:42:25)
    at  .../node_modules/everyauth/lib/modules/twitter.js:16:15
    at passBackControl ( .../node_modules/everyauth/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:359:11)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> ( .../node_modules/everyauth/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:378:9)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:88:20)
```

Users looks like:

```
var cradle = require('cradle');
var c = new cradle.Connection('...', 80, {
    auth:{username:'admin', password:'...'}
});
var users = c.database('users');

module.exports.findOrCreateByTwitterData = function(twitterUserData, promise) {
    console.log('finding');
    users.view('docs/twitterId', {key:twitterUserData.id_str}, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('twitter error');
            return;
        }
        if (doc) {
            promise.fulfill(doc);
        }
        else {
            var doc = {

            };
        }
        c.database('users').save(doc, function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error with users');
                return;
            }
            promise.fulfill(doc);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What's inside the `users` file?

Comment: You may want to investigate Passport (http://passportjs.org/).  It's a flexible alternative to everyauth, which doesn't use promises, so might be easier to debug in your application.  I'm the developer, feel free to ping me with any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue with everyauth 0.2.32.
Looks like everyauth.Promise is not being exported and the app crashes when you try to instantiate an 'undefined' class

You can check if (Promise == 'undefined')

Answer (score 0):

in recent versions of everyauth you should use following syntax:

```
.findOrCreateUser(function(session, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, twitterUserData) {
    var promise = this.Promise();
    users.findOrCreateByTwitterData(twitterUserData, promise);
    return promise;
})
```